# what is the possible reason for require a file but it did not run

Tags: ruby, require

what might be the possible reason?

```
#wordlist.rb
code_words = {
'starmonkeys' => 'Phil and Pete, those prickly chancellors of the New Reich',
'catapult' => 'chucky go-go', 'firebomb' => 'Heat-Assisted Living',
'Nigeria' => "Ny and Jerry's Dry Cleaning (with Donuts)",
'Put the kabosh on' => 'Put the cable box on'
}


irb(main):001:0> require 'wordlist.rb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> code_words
NameError: undefined local variable or method `code_words' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
    from :0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for [Kernel#load](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001417) says

> In no circumstance will any local
>   variables in the loaded file be
>   propagated to the loading environment.

As piyush says a global or constant is fine.

Answer (score 2):

declare it as constant or global variable. code_words lives inside the scope of require and dies/not-accessible after it has loaded.